# Handle 500 errors using jQuery/ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have this jQuery method that gives parameters for a ssh session, wait for the output and prints it in a text area.

It is working really great but if the user write a wrong password all I get is 500 error in the background.

TL; DR : How can I modify this to be able to handle 500 errors?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (event) {
        $.post("/ssh/execute", {
            hostname: $('#serverlist').val(),
            username: $('#login').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            command: $('#CommandSelect').val()
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#textarea").text(data.result);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `$.post()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax()` you can use the `statusCode` option to create callbacks for various possible response codes, such as a 500 error

```
$.post("/ssh/execute", {
  hostname: $('#serverlist').val(),
  username: $('#login').val(),
  password: $('#password').val(),
  command: $('#CommandSelect').val(),
  statusCode: {
    500: function() {
    ...some callback...
    }
  }
}).done(function (data){
  ...
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to make it work.. pretty sure the logic I use is wrong        $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(event){
    $.post( "/ssh/execute", { 
      hostname: $('#serverlist').val(), 
      username: $('#login').val(), 
      password: $('#password').val(), 
      command: $('#CommandSelect').val()
      }).done(function( data ) {
       statusCode: {
                    500: function(data) {
                    $("#textarea").text("wrong password");
                   }
       }
    
      });
    });
    });

Comment: try adding the `statusCode:...` to the `$.post()` options, not the `$.done()` options

Comment: updated my answer, yeah you can remove `.done()` if you arent going to be using it

Comment: thank you very much! last thing : if my password is ok it prints both the error message and the success result.. do you know why? have updated my gist :https://gist.github.com/gcaille/9687480

Comment: I still want it to print the result when it succeed. Is there a Statuscode for when it works ?

Comment: yeah, 200.  here is a very [good reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: thank you for the site it is a very good reference. I made the modifications and now it just don't run at all.. https://gist.github.com/gcaille/9687480  any clue ?

Comment: To be more precise, if I miss-spell the password it prints the correct error code. If I do it right and get 200:ok in the background it does nothing at all for the user

Comment: I will set like it worked but this isn't 100% working

Comment: if your code is still the same as it was, the reason nothing is showing up when the user uses correct password is because you are using `data.retour` which is no longer available because you aren't using `$.done()` anymore